# Is there a way to get the list of trigger events in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

It is possible to figure out the list of events or event groups for particular trigger?
Actually I need some query that returns the list (or table) of events.

This question concerns to DML and DDL DB-scoped triggers.

Comment: By events, do you mean whether a given trigger is for/instead of insert/update/delete?

Comment: @Fergus Bown, Yes, for DML triggers insert/update/delete. And for DDL - Events: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522542(v=sql.110).aspx, Event Groups: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510452(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: And will be nice to figure out the query for trigger "time" - FOR/AFTER/INSTEAD OF :). It is no big problem for other DBMS like MySQL or Postgre, but is not obvious for the SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you..

```
 SELECT SO.NAME
    , SE.*
FROM sys.trigger_events SE
INNER JOIN sys.objects SO
    ON SE.object_id = SO.object_id
```

This query gives a list of triggers in the database along with their type description.
If you need it for a particular trigger use `WHERE` condition.

```
SELECT SO.NAME
    , SE.*
FROM sys.trigger_events SE
INNER JOIN sys.objects SO
    ON SE.object_id = SO.object_id
WHERE SO.name = 'trigger_name'
```

Comment: This solution works. But may be you mean INNER JOIN sys.triggers ? Because  for sys.objects - the result is empty (tested on DDL triggers).